# CakePHP: Cakefile in conflict with CoffeeScript

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, coffeescript

When I'm trying to use the 'cake' command, I always getting this error. It seems its in a conflict with CoffeeScript.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:108
throw new Error("Cakefile not found in " + (process.cwd()));
      ^
Error: Cakefile not found in /Users/kevingorjan/e-Merce/Learning/CakePHP/Blog_demo/lib/Cake/Console
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:108:11
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how I can change it?

Comment: Okay, I added the PATH in bashrc, reloaded the bashrc and it didn't work. Now I changed the "cake"-command in CoffeeScript to "cakes", now it works perfectly, but I don't think this is the right solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, found it, changed it and now it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ vi .bash_profile`

I have node and coffeescript and all sorts of things in my path. My .bash_profile has these lines in it:

```
#Path
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

When I added the the cake stuff to my path like they suggest http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#adding-cake-to-your-path I get the same error you got:

```
#Path
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/eO_Ae/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console"
```

What I did to fix it is:

```
# Cake PHP
PATH="/Users/eO_Ae/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console:$PATH"

# Path
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin"

export PATH
```

This gives the cakephp `cake` shell command priority over the coffescript one.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution better than above!

Comment: Solve my problem! Thanks!